# Is it a sensible strategy to call setuid twice to clear the saved set-user ID?

Tags: linux, privileges, setuid

For a program I'm developing, there's no reason why it should ever be run with setuid bit set - that always represents a configuration error on the part of the user. As part of defense in depth, I'd like to detect and fix that in the program.

As I understand that, to really do that, I have to call `setuid` *twice*, like this:

```
uid_t real_uid = getuid();
int ret = setuid(real_uid);
/* error checking here */
ret = setuid(real_uid);
/* error checking here */
```

As I understand it, if I only call `setuid` once, then the old effective UID would be in the saved set-user-ID, so any injected call to `setuid` (assume a vulnerability that somehow enables that) could be used to set the effective UID back to its original value. The second call to `setuid` puts the new value in the saved set-user-ID, fixing this. Is this a reasonable way to achieve this?

Alternatively, at least on Linux (in practice that's where this will always be run), I could use `setresuid` to do this all on one go:

```
uid_t real_uid = getuid();
int ret = setresuid(-1, real_uid, real_uid);
/* error checking here */
```

Is that (more) reasonable?

Does all of this apply to GIDs too? Do I need to worry about the supplementary group list at all (I don't really know what this is)?

Comment: Should you just compare `getuid()` and `geteuid()` ?

Comment: @Philippe And what do you suggest I do if they do not match? I could show an error and exit I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

`setuid()` once is sufficient to go from `root` to another user and prevent `setuid()` back to `root`. It has no special effects when the other user isn't `root`.

#### Explanation

The concept you are talking about is a *drop in privilege*.

It is often that a service starts as `root` so it can open and listen on a socket with a port under 1024 (i.e. Apache2 has to open ports 80 and 443 as `root` before becoming `www-data` or some other user). Those sockets can only be opened by the `root` user. So the synopsis of such a service is:

```
... do some basic initialization ...
uid_t const me(getuid());
seteuid(0); // or setuid(0); -- it works either way in this direction
... socket()/bind() ...
setuid(me);
... listen() ...
```

The part between the `setuid(0)` and the `setuid(me)` should be as small as possible to make it as safe as possible.

To learn more about this I suggest you closely read the following two manual pages:

```
man setuid
man seteuid
```

*(on some systems, it may be the same manual page, under Linux, it should be two separate pages).*

The `seteuid()` clearly says it only changes the effective user ID.

The `setuid()` clearly says that going from `root` to another user is a one time event:

> If the user is root or the program is set-user-ID-root, special care
> must be taken: `setuid()` checks the effective user ID of the caller
> and if it is the superuser, all process-related user ID's are set to
> `uid`. After this has occurred, it is impossible for the program to
> regain root privileges.

So checking the `s` bit and trying to prevent `setuid()` between users when not `root` has no special effects. It's really only from `root` (superuser) to another user.

#### Example

Create a file named `a.cpp` with:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    uid_t const me(getuid());
    uid_t const other(0);   // try with another user and no errors happen

    // you can go back and forth any number of times with seteuid()
    for(int i(0); i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "seteuid(): change to other: " << seteuid(other) << "\n";
        std::cout << "seteuid(): change back: " << seteuid(me) << "\n";
    }

    // however, with setuid(), if you drop privileges from root,
    // you can't come back
    for(int i(0); i < 5; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "setuid(): change to other: " << setuid(other) << "\n";
        std::cout << "setuid(): change back: " << setuid(me) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ -o a a.cpp
```

Change ownership and set the `s` bit of that executable:

```
sudo chown root a
sudo chmod u+s a
```

Finally execute:

```
./a
```

Here is the output when the other user is `root`:

> seteuid(): change to other: 0
> seteuid(): change back: 0
> seteuid(): change to other: 0
> seteuid(): change back: 0
> seteuid(): change to other: 0
> seteuid(): change back: 0
> seteuid(): change to other: 0
> seteuid(): change back: 0
> seteuid(): change to other: 0
> seteuid(): change back: 0
> setuid(): change to other: 0
> setuid(): change back: 0
> setuid(): change to other: -1
> setuid(): change back: 0
> setuid(): change to other: -1
> setuid(): change back: 0
> setuid(): change to other: -1
> setuid(): change back: 0
> setuid(): change to other: -1
> setuid(): change back: 0

As we can see, a single `setuid()` was sufficient to kill your ability to come back as `root` (whether with `setuid()` as presented here, or `seteuid()` and I will leave that as a test for you to verify I'm correct).

If the other user is set to a different user (other than `root`), then the rules change and you can't prevent the back and forth either way. Say you change the user identifier like so:

```
    uid_t const other(65534);   // the nobody user (verify ID in /etc/passwd)
```

Recompile and run `a`. The output has no `-1`. The switching back and forth works as expected, and you can try with as many `setuid()` in a raw as you like, it has no special effects. You could replicate this line to make double sure:

```
        std::cout << "setuid(): change back: " << setuid(me) << "\n";
        std::cout << "setuid(): change back: " << setuid(me) << "\n";
        std::cout << "setuid(): change back: " << setuid(me) << "\n";
```

#### Side Note

I do not use SELinux. The rules on that version of Linux may be slightly different. See details about the `CAP_SETUID` flag.